# Node js. Проблемы с подключением модулей

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, модули

**Вступительная часть**

Очень необычная ошибка, связанная, как мне кажется с циклами между вызовами модулей (т.к. иначе даже предположить не могу с чем).
Не редко в программировании, когда приходилось делить программу на модули, сталкивался с проблемой циклов модулей (когда модули вызывают друг друга непосредственно или через цепочку других модулей). Но с Node js, как мне показалось, такая проблема отсутствует, поэтому за этим не следил, но сейчас похоже с этим проблема, хотя не могу отследить.

**Основная часть**

У меня есть модуль который отвечает за мелкие функции вроде "Сказать от имени сервера" и он, очевидно, задействован в большом количестве других модулей. *moduleFunctions.js*

И есть ест модуль который хранит в себе функции инициирующие основные функции самой программы *moduleCommands.js*. (И он тоже использует *moduleFunctions.js*)

Все работало нормально, пока мне не понадобилось вызвать модуль *moduleCommands.js* внутри *moduleFunctions.js*. И после этого программа перестала видеть экспорта из *moduleFunctions.js* вообще в третьем модуле (при чем именно в нем, в остальных видит).

Долго не мог понять, в чем проблема, пока не отрубил импорт *moduleCommands.js* внутри *moduleFunctions.js* и все опять заработало.

проектик еще совсем маленький, вот ссылка на гитхаб, чтобы легко увидеть связть модулей и сам код: https://github.com/VovaParamonov/webbot

Так же код из двух "главных участников действий" (модулей):

*moduleFunctions.js*

```
const clc = require('cli-color');
const { commands } = require("./moduleCommands");

module.exports.serverSay = function serverSay(text) {
    console.log(`[SERVER]: ${text}`);
};

module.exports.serverErr = function serverErr(text) {
    console.log(clc.red(`[SERVER ERROR]: ${text}`))
};

module.exports.serverCommandsList = function serverCommandsList () {
    Object.keys(commands).forEach(commandName => console.log(commandName));
};
```

*moduleCommands.js*

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const { createRequest } = require("./moduleRequests");
const { serverSay } = require("./moduleFunctions");


module.exports.commands = {
    "omgtuInformation" : function omgtuInformation() {
        createRequest("https://omgtu.ru/", (body, status) => {
            const $ = cheerio.load(body);

            serverSay(`New information from site: ${$("#menu_banner2").text()}`);
        })
    }
};
```

P.S.
Понимаю, что многие будут писать о проблемах в архитектуре, раз мне понадобились такие циклические связи между модулями и мне достаточно исправить это, но мне нужно понять как с этим ли точно проблема, чтобы не сталкиваться с ней в дальнейшем. В google вообще ничего похожего с циклами модулей node js не нашел, а больше не знаю, в какую сторону копать.

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В документации `Node.js` по модулям есть отдельный [раздел](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles) про циклические зависимости. Суть проблемы в том, что `require` возвращает ссылку на "недоделанный" модуль при обнаружении цикла и окончательно определяет все экспорты только по завершении всех импортов. Ошибка возникает при попытке деструктуризации этой ссылки в незавершенном состоянии.